# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am newbie to node.js I was trying to implement the [example](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34243127010/knocking-out-socket-io). when i run `node app.js` i am getting map error which is given below:

**Error**

```
oneadmin@openflow1:~/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example$ node app.js
   info  - socket.io started
/home/oneadmin/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example/app.js:17
    io.sockets.emit('tweets', obj.results.map(function (v) { return v.text; })
                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/home/oneadmin/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example/app.js:17:42)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/oneadmin/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example/node_modules/request/main.js:122:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/oneadmin/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example/node_modules/request/main.js:655:16)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/oneadmin/Desktop/test-projects/nodejs/example/node_modules/request/main.js:617:14)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:895:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:11)
```

**app.js**

```
var sio = require('socket.io')
  , http = require('http')
  , index = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html')
  , request = require('request')

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(index);
  })
  , io = sio.listen(app);

setInterval(function () {
  request({
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=today'
  }, function (err, res, data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    io.sockets.emit('tweets', obj.results.map(function (v) { return v.text; }));
  });
}, 2000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('someone connected');

  socket.on('some event', function () {
    console.log('I got an event');
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();

      $(function () {
        socket.on('tweets', function (tweets) {
          $.each(tweets, function (i, tweet) {
            $('#tweets').prepend($('<li>').text(tweet));
          });
        });

        socket.on('someone connected', function () {
          $('body').prepend('<p>Someone just connected!</p>');
        });

        socket.emit('some event');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tweets</h1>
    <ul id="tweets"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any one help me to remove this error
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you recieve right response object (```obj```) in line 16, but this obj not contains ```results``` field. Check the structure of parsed object (```console.log(obj)```)

Comment: you r right....When i tryied another url http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=Europe/Brussels i got same error

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check the returned value before using it:

```
    if (obj && obj.results) {
        io.sockets.emit('tweets', obj.results.map(function (v) { 
             return v.text; 
        }));
    }
```

But the real question is: why obj.results is undefined?  I checked the url http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=today and it returned this:

{
    errors: [
        {
            message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please          migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
            code: 64
        }
    ]
}

That's why obj.results is undefined.